# Go compiles declared and not used

Tags: go

I got some problems with Go, I did have used tag  in `tag = true`

```
//  project main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var m, odd1, odd2, in1, in2 int
    tag := false
    fmt.Scan(&m)
    for i := 0; i < m; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&in1, &in2)
        odd1 += in1
        odd2 += in2
        if (in1+in2)&1 == 1 {
            tag = true
        }
    }
    if odd1&1 == 0 && odd2&1 == 0 {
        fmt.Print("0")
        return
    }
    if odd1&1 == 0 && odd2&1 == 1 || odd1&1 == 1 && odd2&1 == 0 {
        fmt.Print("1")
        return
    }
    fmt.Print("-1")
}
```

Comment: You aren't *using* tag.  You're assigning to it again.  Using would mean it's on the right hand side of something: `if tag {` or if `tag && odd1 && 1 == testVal {`

Comment: @SethHoenig No, in the question you posted the variable is declared twice, thus shadowing the one. In this case the variable is just not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Not used' can be understood as 'has no effect'. While you're assigning `true` to `tag`,
this is not propagated to the outside nor has any effect on the result of the function.

If you'd use `tag` in a condition or return it, then the compiler wouldn't complain anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using tag. You're assigning to it again. Using would mean it's on the right hand side of something: `if tag { or if tag && odd1 && 1 == testVal {`

<sub>This is a Christopher Pfohl answer</sub>